# render only some parts of the texture Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader

as the title described i want to render only some parts of the texture. For example i have an 1024*1024 texture and now i want to render the area(square) that's between the points 0/0 50/50 pixel and the area 600/600 1024/1024.

Is something like that possible?
Maybe you can help me with some logic steps that i need to go, because i don't really know how to start.
Yeah i need an shader with 2 texture slots and a scripts that renders only some parts^^

I think it has something to do with this here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/529814/how-to-have-2-different-objects-at-the-same-place.html

Answer (score 0):

The following basic surface shader "removes" all pixels outside between 50/50 and 600/600 (this is called clipping):

```
Shader "Custom/ClippedTexture" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            float u = IN.uv_MainTex.x * _MainTex_TexelSize.x;
            float v = IN.uv_MainTex.y * _MainTex_TexelSize.y;

            if((u < 51 && v < 51) || (u > 599 && v > 599)) {
                clip(-1); // skip pixel
            } else {
                o.Albedo = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb;
            }
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

You can save this Shader into the Shader directory of your project and create a material that uses it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think he wanted it to only render the pixels between 0/0 -> 50/50 and the area between 600/600 -> 1024/1024... Also not sure UV's in unity are whole numbers, I will have to look into this but typically in shaders they are between 0f - 1f...

Comment: You're right. I updated the shader to clip between 50/50 -> 600/600. Thanks for the hint. You're also right about the UV's being between 0f and 1f. That's why I'm calculating pixel coordinates using `_MainTex_TexelSize`.

Comment: ahh I completely missed that haha!  but um your `if` statement wont work... if should be if u > 50 && u < 600 || v > 50 && V < 600  (1 < 600... 601 > 50)

Comment: Hmm but that allows all 4 corners to draw so maybe instead of clipping just write `if(u < 50 && v < 50 || u > 600 && v > 600)`  then draw it, otherwise clip it...

Comment: You're right! Now it should clip pixels outside of 0/0 -> 50/50 and 600/600 -> 1024/1024. Thanks again!

Comment: Soo i used your code, but i get an error. " invalid subscript 'u' " d3d11 20 " .

Comment: The shader has problems with first line "u = IN.uv_MainTex.u * _MainTex_TexelSize.x"

Comment: It should be `IN.uv_MainTex.x`. I fixed that.

Comment: Did this help you?